# Getting a variable value from a webpage

Tags: android, http

I need to get variable values from a webpage on android.  Presently I have the lines I need, but with their variable names (pfname, plname) instead of their values.  Code as follows, school removed from website:

```
    public void getJSON(View view) throws IOException {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.
    ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    JSONObject input = readRateMyProfessor();
    try {
        Log.i("JSON", json.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, String.valueOf(input));
    startActivity(intent);
}

public JSONObject readRateMyProfessor() throws IOException {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.ratemyprofessors.com");

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        try {
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        // json is UTF-8 by default
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("<li>")) {
                if (!line.contains("http") || !line.contains("about") || !line.contains("blog") || !line.contains("help")
                        || !line.contains("Contact") || !line.contains("TermsOfUse")) {
                    if ((line = reader.readLine()).contains("ShowRatings"))
                        while (!(line = reader.readLine()).contains("</a>")) {
                            if (line.contains("name")) {
                                String[] parts = line.split(">");
                                String[] parts2 = parts[1].split("<");
                                name = parts2[0];
                            } else if (line.contains("rating")) {
                                String[] parts = line.split(">");
                                String[] parts2 = parts[1].split("<");
                                rating = Integer.valueOf(parts2[0]);
                            }
                            json = new JSONObject();
                            json.put(name, rating);
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    }
    return json;
}
```

EDIT:

Some sample output I'm getting:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujHle.png

And then repeats this for every professor at the school.  I'm not concerned about the excess I'm getting, I can trim that

Comment: If you get the variable instead of value, probably something wrong on the server. Could you post a sample response and what you want from it?

Comment: Edited, thanks.  And I don't think it's the server since it displays properly when I view the page on my computer.  And when viewing the code in chrome It has the variables filled in with their values so I'm just at a wall.

Comment: Well it seems those `{{something}}` are for the `js` library (handlebars.js) you're using which are then changed on browser, since you're getting the server response directly, those variables are returned as is.

Comment: Okay - but is there a way for me to actually get the values?

Comment: You're getting the response from http://www.ratemyprofessors.com ? Cause I don't see elements in your response in the source of that page. e.g `<span class="rating"`

Comment: I'm getting the variable name, not the variable value, that's the issue I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue as you previously mentioned in your question. What I'm asking though is, what is the URL you're getting the response from? Cause I can't see a span with for example class rating in http://www.ratemyprofessors.com . If it's from the live site maybe you can tell what page it. It'd be easier to find a solution the way you're already doing (going through the whole DOM to find a couple of variables). The proper way though would be to send a couple of parameters along with your URL and the getting only the response to those quesries instead of getting the whole page.